# Rails4 - How to make regular expression for name of a user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

I have name of the user in my user model as follows. The user name is not unique.

```
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 30 }
  validates_length_of :name, :minimum => 6
  validates_format_of :name, :with => /\A[a-zA-Z ]+\z/,  :message => "must contain only letters and space"
```

I want users to be able to provide their names with alphabets and space as follows and also prevent users from just adding space and exploit the user name.

```
Valid = "Neil deGrasse Tyson"   
Invalid = "            "
Invalid = "  a         "
Invalid = "b           "
Invalid = "           c"
```

How do I implement this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an optional group instead of allowing the space character inside of the character class.

```
/\A[a-zA-Z]+(?: [a-zA-Z]+)*\z/
```